# SSH: login as user A, but once logged in, prompt appears as ROOT

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, root, prompt

I use putty to connect to a remote Gnu/Linux (Red Hat) through SSH on port 22, direct to IP.

First it asks for user name. I enter it.
Then it asks for password. I enter it,
Then it connects. But prompt appears as:

```
root@xxxxxxx$
```

If I write: whoami, it says "root".
If I try a su - THEUSER, then it asks me for the password again, and once in, I am back to root prompt again...

I need to put myself on USER prompt to change it's password via "passwd", to be sure I'm altering THEUSER's password, and not ROOT's password.

So, what's going on?

Sorry for the probably noob question...

Thanks you all!

Comment: What is the output of `id THEUSER` (or at least `id -u THEUSER`)?

Comment: Assuming you're running `bash`, what is the output of `grep PS1 ~/.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/bashrc /etc/profile.d/*`?

Comment: Also, if you just want to change the password for a particular user, try `passwd THEUSER`

Comment: Could you run `grep :$UID: /etc/passwd` from the prompt just after you login. To make sure someone hasn't given your user an extra line with 'root' as the name.

Comment: `getent passwd THEUSER` is better than grepping /etc/passwd - there are many other possible sources that could define a passwd entry (e.g. ldap, nis, .db, *sql, etc) depending on what's in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: id THEUSER = uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1004(beoper) || id -u THEUSER = 0

Comment: getent passwd THEUSER = THEUSER:x:0:1005::/home/THEUSER:/bin/bash

Comment: passwd THEUSER, did the trick. Thanks to all! Anyway, if someone could give feedback on previous tests results, would be great, as it looks my user is full root.

Comment: @Lightworker given that the gid is 1005, the uid is probably supposed to be 1005 too.   see `man usermod` and search for the `-u` option for a way to fix this `usermod -u 1005 THEUSER`. this will change the uid in /etc/passwd and change the ownership of the user's home dir (and all files & dirs under it).  It won't change ownership of any files outside the home dir (you'd have to be extremely careful fixing those if any exist because you really don't want to change owner on root-owned files that **should** belong to root).

Comment: you will have to log out and log back in again after you change THEUSER's uid,